# How can I get the embed id for Slideshare from the complete URL?

Tags: javascript, embed

I want to let user add Slideshare presentation and Youtube video on my Website. I don't want them to go through the trouble of finding the embeded code, I want to generate it myself so I determine the size and protocole and they just have to copy the URL they see in the address bar.

It was easy to do with Youtube, I just had to extract the video id. It doesn't seem that easy with Slideshare since the full URL doesn't contain the id that is used when embedding the presentation.

So basically, I want to know how to go from this

http://www.slideshare.net/guest196e23/joel-spolsky-100-things-keynote

to

http://www.slideshare.net/slideshow/embed_code/4053571

Or even more precisely, from "guest196e23/joel-spolsky-100-things-keynote" to "4053571"

I would like a client-side (javascript) solution.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You'll have to load the given URL page and parse it on server side (e.g.: with PHP). Look for this HTML tag: `<meta name="twitter:player" class="twitter_player" value="https://www.slideshare.net/slideshow/embed_code/4053571" />` within the `<HEAD>` tag contents. Convert the `https:` protocol to `http:`.

Comment: Thanks Jay for this pointer. I didn't want to add complexity by adding ajax request so for now, I asked a bit more effort to my users. They must copy the embed code and I extract the id from there. It will do for now, but it will be really cool that SlideShare works like Youtube for this!

Comment: @Melanie, Did you get any solution to extract embed code from url in clientside(Javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve that using Node.js and JSDOM

```
jsdom.env(
  "http://www.slideshare.net/DonaldDerek/build-your-own-raspitv-with-nodejs-socketio",
  ["http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"],
  function (errors, window) {
    var $ = window.$ , 
        presentation = $(".twitter_player").attr('value')

    if(presentation === undefined){
      res.json({error:true})  
    }
    else{
      res.json({presentation_embed:presentation, error:false})
    }
  }
)
```

Then simply catch the response inside your AJAX Callback.

Comment: I'm guessing we cant do this just client-side?